# Duck typing: How to implicitly convert from an interface to another interface in go

Tags: go, interface, type-conversion

I'm new to go and I wish to make two packages with (very) loosely coupled API between a uses and a provider. For this, I wish to use go's ability to implicitly implement interfaces and implicit conversion.

Both the provider and the user have their own defined interfaces (for exemple provider returns a provider.A and user accepts a user.A).
With this pattern, I can convert from one type to the other instead of importing the interfaces from another package.

This works fine with simple interfaces, but as soon as a method takes an interfaces as an input, the conversion from one type to the other become impossible.

Why doesn't go allow this kind of conversion? Is there any workaround?

working example:

```
package main

// Provider

type A interface{
    AddString(string)
}


type a struct{
    b string
}
func (a *a) AddString(b string) {
    a.b = b
}
func NewA() A {
    return &a{nil}
}


// User

type A2 interface{
    AddString(string)
}

func Main() {
    var _ A2 = NewA()
}
```

example that cause problems:

```
package main

// Provider

type A interface{
    AddB(B)
}
type B interface{}


type a struct{
    b B
}
func (a *a) AddB(b B) {
    a.b = b
}
func NewA() A {
    return &a{nil}
}


// User

type A2 interface{
    AddB(B2)
}
type B2 interface{}

func Main() {
    var _ A2 = NewA() // error..
}
```

Comment: That's probably not how interfaces are used in Go. I have t oadmit I have no idea what you are trying to do.

Comment: Ok, first this is not for a serious project, this is just me toying around. My goal here is to see if I can create an API with absolutely zero coupling what so ever using some kind of duck-typing. The user doesn't know anything about the provider and the provider doesn't know anything about the user, they are hosted on separated gits, and can't import from one another. The wiring is done by dependency-injection. The user tells what it needs (interface A2) and the provider what it provide (interface A). And I was hoping that A could be converted to A2 since the interfaces are the same.

Answer (score 2):

Go provides type checking as a feature, not a bug.  When you declare B and B2 to be separate types, the compiler respects this distinction and treats them differently.

A familiar example is `time.Duration`, which is just an `int64` to count nanoseconds, but you cannot mix and match variables that are `int64` and `time.Duration` without an explicit type conversion. [see time.Duration docs](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Duration)

Rather than trying to work around Go's type checking feature, you should try to learn how to express your algorithm using idiomatic Go.

Comment: The point here is to toy around and see the limit of the language, not about writing idiomatic go. (See my 1st comment on the question.) I was aware of the problems with redefining built-in types and with the slice of interfaces. But this is yet-another case where I can't implicitly convert from one interface to another...

Comment: @Matthieu Yes, this is intentional.